# Select Unbooked Room from Arrival and Departure Date

Tags: mysql, sql, between, cross-join

I have a table named room

> id     room
> 1     Room 1
> 2     Room 2

And a table named order

> id     id_room    date_arrival     date_departure
> 1     1                2018-09-13     2018-09-15
> 2     1                2018-09-27     2018-09-29

And when I choose date_arrival in 2018-09-14 and date_departure in 2018-09-20 I want an unbooked room that appears.

Comment: Order is a reserved word, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

Try this: it's a overlapping range problem

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9746d6/6

```
SELECT room.id, rname from
room  left join `roomorder`
on room.id=`roomorder`.id_room
and '2018-09-14' < date_departure AND '2018-09-20' > date_arrival
```

Comment: It's still a reserved word though

Comment: With this INNER JOIN, you will not get the room 2 in your result, which is the unbooked room. You should change to a `LEFT JOIN` and edit your `WHERE` clause to catch the `NULL` date rows